# Why can't you drag/drop files from inside an archive to mounted devices in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, android, zip, archiving, drag-and-drop

Why is it when you have an archive open (for example using Winrar) that you can't drag and drop it's contents onto a mounted device in Windows Explorer such as the SD card in cellphones and tablets but you can on the desktop? For example if I download a .zip file I'm unable to move a file inside of it directly to my tablet.

Comment: Well... maybe something specific to Winrar? With works with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Or there is something else going on with your computer. Even the zip-manager of Windows itself has no trouble with this.

Answer (score 4):

This probably has to do with the fact that the SD cards, phones, what-not aren't actual drives per se, but (as far as I know) work via [Shell Namespace Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yep. Just tested it and 7zip also doesn't drop it on my GT-I9100. The question is slightly misleading (asking `... to SD cards`). +1

Comment: @Rik so what is the nature, help me edit the question not to be misleading...

Comment: @Celeritas I tried to clarify the title and body of the question (with "mounted devices"). Feel free to Rollback (if not agreed with) or append to it.